# Why do event handlers in a class not inherit variables from that class

Tags: javascript, class, mouseevent

In the example code, myOtherFunc prints the inherited canvas variable, but when one clicks on the canvas to call myFunc, this.canvas prints as undefined. Why is this?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  <canvas id="drawCanvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
  <script>
    class myClass {
      constructor() {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById('drawCanvas');
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

        this.canvas.addEventListener('click', this.myFunc);

        this.myOtherFunc();
      }

      myFunc(event) {
        console.log(this.canvas);
      }

      myOtherFunc() {
        console.log(this.canvas);
      }
    }

    let c = new myClass;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is the `<canvas>` element itself within `click` event handler attached to the `canvas` element. `this`:`<canvas>` does not have a `.canvas` property set at  element at code at Question, resulting in `undefined` being logged at `console`

```
myFunc(event) {
  console.log(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also the really useful:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('click', this);
```

If you pass an object instead of a function, then handleEvent in that object will be called, and the this will be the object. Inside handleEvent you can check the event.type to figure out the kind of event. An example:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
        element.addEventListener("mousedown", this);
        element.addEventListener("mousemove", this);
        element.addEventListener("mouseup", this);
    }
    handleEvent(event) {
        // all events come here, so lets redistribute them:
        this[event.type](event);
    }
    mousemove(event) {
    }
    mousedown(event) {
    }
    mouseup(event) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the event handler's scope is the canvas, not the class. You need to *bind* `this` to the event handler:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('click', this.myFunc.bind(this));
```

For more information about `bind`, see [this MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).